# Print selected option with Chrome print selection only

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

Is it possible to print user selected select box option with chrome "selection only" option.

example:

```
Lorem ipsum
<select>
    <option value="2">2 months</option>
    <option value="3">3 months</option>
    <option value="4">4 months</option>
</select>
```

When I select "4 months" and select only the select box with mouse and I hit ctrl + P I see this: 
[image]

And now when I choose from left "More options" -> "Selection only" then I see
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use [media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp) for that! And it will work with every (modern) browser!

Check this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/utf0Lapk/)

HTML:

```
<span class="label">
Lorem ipsum
</span>
<select>
    <option value="2">2 months</option>
    <option value="3">3 months</option>
    <option value="4">4 months</option>
</select>
```

CSS:

```
@media print {
    .label {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}
```